# Configure SQL Server merge replication in local machine and a server machines

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, merge-replication

I have two databases on my local machine and the server. I want to sync them whenever they are being changed. For my scenario I'm using SQL Server replication.

I use merge type to sync these databases twoway. I'm placing the distributor in my server and I have created publisher is my server. And the publisher is running when I'm reaching it from replication monitor.

On my local machine, I have created a subscriber to that publisher but I can't connect to my publisher.

I followed these steps to solve this problem.

- I have turned off my firewalls in both machines
- SQL Server browsing is running in both machines
- Remote connection is enabled on both
- TCP is enabled on both
- I don't have any errors in SQL Server logs in neither of them
- SQL Server service is running on both

I'm stuck in a loop and do not know what to do to make it work.

Do you have any ideas how I can make it work?

Is it possible at all to connect them when I'm using local machine and server?

***UPDATE***

I Find out that they have to be in the same network and as my local machine doesn't have any ip address I tried to use OpenSSH for reverse tunneling and i didn't reach any result

***UPDATE_2***

after i tried to connect via static ip address, i can ping my subscriber on my publication machine via telnet but in replication monitor i get this error

[image]

Comment: "*I have created a subscriber to that publisher but I can't connect to my publisher.*" - What does this mean?...do you get an error (and what does it say)?...or do you not see the Publisher when trying to create the Subscriber? Is the server on the same domain as the local machine?

Comment: @J.D.
they are not in the same network but i tried to use reverse tunneling with OpenSSH but didnt work
The process could not connect to Distributor 'SRV150659'. this is my error and nothing else
subscriber could not found on publisher machine cause they are not in the same network and subscriber is in a local machine and dont have static ip address

Comment: I'm thinking this is going to turn into a networking question, which would be better served by [NetworkEngineering.StackExchange.com](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) but are you able to `ping` the server from your local machine? How about from the other direction too?

Comment: @J.D. yes i can ping both machines from each other
the error that im having is
"The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may have been unable to create or write to the message file. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write"

Comment: Please put error messages and detailed updates in your Post. If you open up the Replication Monitor, does it show any more details or errors on why it's failing?

Comment: @J.D. I've updated the question with the error and detail